# cmd window does not close after executing python

Tags: python, cmd, exit

I have a bat file that used to execute powershell scripts and using the EXIT it would at the end close the cmd window. Since i switched the powershells with python-selenium scripts it completely ignores all the EXITs and stays open forever. Any ideas to close the window?

in the BAT:

```
C:\Users\...\python.exe C:\Users\...\seleniumskript.py
EXIT
```

The EXIT does not execute...

The python script:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Edge
driver = Edge()
...doing stuff
driver.close()
quit()
```

Comment: Did you try removing the "quit()" statement from python module?

Comment: tried it just now. does not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `chromedriver.exe` is still running in background.
You should try a replacement:

type `browser.quit()` instead of `browser.close()`.

This will let the `chromedriver.exe` to close correctly.

Comment: oh yeah that did the trick. Thnx very much

Comment: For next readers, can you mark my answer as accepted ?

Comment: Sorry i cannot upvote yet though... not enough reputation.

Comment: +10 for you! See ya